# AJAX multiple values inside PHP Echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm struggeling with making an AJAX url inside of an php echo. Other troubleshooters around the internet didn't get me through it. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });

        var ajax_load = "";

        $( "#'.$row_items['id_aanbod'].'" ).change(function() {
            $("#res").html(ajax_load).load("update.php", "e=" +             $("#'.$row_items['id_aanbod'].'").val() & "id=" + $("#hrr").attr("id"));
        });
    });
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The strange thing is that if I use only one variable the script works like it should, but as soon as I insert the second part there is nothing happening. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where is $row_items['id_aanbod'] coming from? A database result? You should <?php echo $row_items['id_aanbod'];?> inside the jquery selector.

Comment: Why not just read the [documentation for load](https://api.jquery.com/load/), and you'll see that it doesn't accept a second argument consisting of a querystring. If you want to send data, add it to the url.

Comment: wheres the error, how is it not working? errors in dev console? are php errors turned on?

Comment: the "&" has to be inside the string?! Something like: "$("#res").html(ajax_load).load("update.php", "e=" +             $("#'.$row_items['id_aanbod'].'").val() + "&id=" + $("#hrr").attr("id"));"... maybe?

Comment: @adeneo I'm pretty sure you can use a query string there. As it is a short-hand method for `$.ajax()` with some added functionalities, the `data` parameter can be both a query string (correctly encoded obviously...) or an object.

Comment: @jeroen - you're right, it does accept a string as data, and looking at it more carefully, I'd actually say the issue is loading jQuery after the script tag, and the console would probably show a `$ is not defined` error.

Comment: @adeneo I thought about that as well, but as it works with one variable, that's probably not it. Misplaced `&` seems to fit.

Comment: Well, it seams like there was a little typo, I've selected the first post as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`& "id="`

should be

`+ "&id="`

But for clean code, you could write like below:

```
$("#<?php echo $row_items['id_aanbod']?>").change(function() {
    $("#res").html(ajax_load).load("update.php", {
      e: this.value,
      id: $("#hrr").attr("id")
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    var ajax_load = "";

    $( "#<?=$row_items['id_aanbod']?>" ).change(function() {
        $("#res").html(ajax_load).load("update.php", "e="+$("#<?=$row_items['id_aanbod']?>").val() + "&id=" + $("#hrr").attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Don't forget to check vals. If short open tags is OFF -> then try :

```
<?php echo $row_items['id_aanbod']?>
```